# How does my browser know to refresh when I start nginx?

Tags: nginx, google-chrome

This just happened:

1. Pointed Chrome to my domain where no server is running, but the DNS points to my linode's IP
2. I started a nginx server on my linode
3. To my astonishment, the Chrome window immediately refreshed!

How does it know to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Chrome 'feature'. It continues querying URL even after it shows timeout. 
May be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32575695/disable-chrome-auto-reload-on-time-out-error

Comment: Wow, ok. It reacts so quickly that I thought it couldn't possibly be polling. It must be requesting at least once per second.